# Black Backgroud while custom transition

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, caanimation, catransition

I want to change the view with a custom transition. It's working but the backgroud is dark/black so it's looking kinda wierd.

I tried to add

```
self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

to the delegate but that doesn't solve the problem.

Here's my code of the transition

```
let homeView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        let transition = CATransition()
        transition.duration = 2.3
        transition.type = CATransitionType.reveal
        transition.subtype = CATransitionSubtype.fromLeft
        view.window!.layer.add(transition, forKey: "transition")
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
        present(homeView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the background color during transitions, it is either the window itself:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

the root view controller:

```
if let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController as? YourRootViewController {
    root.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
}
```

the presenting view controller or the transition's container view.

Comment: Place it right before you present and then change it back in the present’s completion handler.